# How to Print UTF-16 Characters in C?

Tags: c, utf-16

i have a file containing UTF-16 characters. i read in the file and can store the characters either in a uint16_t array or a char array (any better choice?)

But how do i print those characters?

Comment: You can't do this portably. You need to describe your implementation: OS and compiler.

Comment: gcc in linux. (need more specifics? e.g. kernel version?)

Comment: That sounds specific enough. I don't know the answer though!

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you want to print to `stdout` or `stderr`. One method would be to use [libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/s/libiconv/) to convert from UTF-16 to UTF-32 (also known as UCS-4) into a wide-character string (`wchar_t`). You could then use `wprintf` and friends to print to the standard streams.

Comment: i tried to do as advised, but seem to hit issues with printing. i posted a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465939/how-to-convert-utf-16-to-utf-32-and-print-the-resulting-wchar-t-in-c