# How to Convert UTF-16 to UTF-32 and Print the Resulting wchar_t in C?

Tags: c, utf-16, iconv, utf-32

i'm trying to print out a string of UTF-16 characters. i posted this question a while back and the advice given was to convert to UTF-32 using iconv and print it as a string of wchar_t.

i've done some research, and managed to code the following:

```
// *c is the pointer to the characters (UTF-16) i'm trying to print
// sz is the size in bytes of the input i'm trying to print

iconv_t icv;
char in_buf[sz];
char* in;
size_t in_sz;
char out_buf[sz * 2];
char* out;
size_t out_sz;

icv = iconv_open("UTF-32", "UTF-16");

memcpy(in_buf, c, sz);

in = in_buf;
in_sz = sz;
out = out_buf;
out_sz = sz * 2;

size_t ret = iconv(icv, &in, &in_sz, &out, &out_sz);
printf("ret = %d\n", ret);
printf("*** %ls ***\n", ((wchar_t*) out_buf));
```

The iconv call always return 0, so i guess conversion should be OK?

However, printing seems to be hit and miss. At times the converted wchar_t string prints OK. Other times, it seems to hit problem while printing the wchar_t, and terminates the printf function call altogether such that even the trailing "***" does not get printed.

i also tried using

```
wprintf(((wchar_t*) "*** %ls ***\n"), out_buf));
```

but nothing ever gets printed.

Am i missing something here?

Reference: [How to Print UTF-16 Characters in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315686/how-to-print-utf-16-characters-in-c)

**UPDATE**

incorporated some of the suggestions in the comments.

updated code:

```
// *c is the pointer to the characters (UTF-16) i'm trying to print
// sz is the size in bytes of the input i'm trying to print

iconv_t icv;
char in_buf[sz];
char* in;
size_t in_sz;
wchar_t out_buf[sz / 2];
char* out;
size_t out_sz;

icv = iconv_open("UTF-32", "UTF-16");

memcpy(in_buf, c, sz);

in = in_buf;
in_sz = sz;
out = (char*) out_buf;
out_sz = sz * 2;

size_t ret = iconv(icv, &in, &in_sz, &out, &out_sz);
printf("ret = %d\n", ret);
printf("*** %ls ***\n", out_buf);
wprintf(L"*** %ls ***\n", out_buf);
```

still the same result, not all the UTF-16 strings get printed (both the printf and the wprintf).

what else could i be missing?

btw, i'm using Linux, and have verified that wchar_t is 4 bytes.

Comment: `wprintf()` needs the format string to have the `L` prefix, e.g. `wprintf(L"*** %ls ***\n", out_buf)`.

Comment: Why are you copying the input to a local buffer `in_buf`? Just use `c` directly...

Comment: Also you cannot legally cast a pointer to a `char` array to a pointer to `wchar_t`. The output buffer needs to have type `wchar_t [n]`.

Comment: Not all platforms use UTF-32 for `wchar_t`, Win doesn't.

Comment: On Linux you can't mix wide (wprintf) and narrow (printf) output in the same application. The first call sets the orientation and can't be changed afterwords. "Once a stream has an orientation, it cannot be changed and persists until the stream is closed." See http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_fwide.htm and http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/852681-wprintf-conflicts-printf-glibc-bug

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a short program that converts UTF-16 to a wide character array and then prints it out.

```
#include <endian.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <iconv.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>

#define FROMCODE "UTF-16"

#if (BYTE_ORDER == LITTLE_ENDIAN)
#define TOCODE "UTF-32LE"
#elif (BYTE_ORDER == BIG_ENDIAN)
#define TOCODE "UTF-32BE"
#else
#error Unsupported byte order
#endif

int main(void)
{
    void *tmp;
    char *outbuf;
    const char *inbuf;
    long converted = 0;
    wchar_t *out = NULL;
    int status = EXIT_SUCCESS, n;
    size_t inbytesleft, outbytesleft, size;
    const char in[] = {
        0xff, 0xfe,
        'H', 0x0,
        'e', 0x0,
        'l', 0x0,
        'l', 0x0,
        'o', 0x0,
        ',', 0x0,
        ' ', 0x0,
        'W', 0x0,
        'o', 0x0,
        'r', 0x0,
        'l', 0x0,
        'd', 0x0,
        '!', 0x0
    };
    iconv_t cd = iconv_open(TOCODE, FROMCODE);
    if ((iconv_t)-1 == cd) {
        if (EINVAL == errno) {
            fprintf(stderr, "iconv: cannot convert from %s to %s\n",
                    FROMCODE, TOCODE);
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "iconv: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        }
        goto error;
    }
    size = sizeof(in) * sizeof(wchar_t);
    inbuf = in;
    inbytesleft = sizeof(in);
    while (1) {
        tmp = realloc(out, size + sizeof(wchar_t));
        if (!tmp) {
            fprintf(stderr, "realloc: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            goto error;
        }
        out = tmp;
        outbuf = (char *)out + converted;
        outbytesleft = size - converted;
        n = iconv(cd, (char **)&inbuf, &inbytesleft, &outbuf, &outbytesleft);
        if (-1 == n) {
            if (EINVAL == errno) {
                /* junk at the end of the buffer, ignore it */
                break;
            } else if (E2BIG != errno) {
                /* unrecoverable error */
                fprintf(stderr, "iconv: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                goto error;
            }
            /* increase the size of the output buffer */
            converted = size - outbytesleft;
            size <<= 1;
        } else {
            /* done */
            break;
        }
    }
    converted = (size - outbytesleft) / sizeof(wchar_t);
    out[converted] = L'\0';
    fprintf(stdout, "%ls\n", out);
    /* flush the iconv buffer */
    iconv(cd, NULL, NULL, &outbuf, &outbytesleft);
exit:
    if (out) {
        free(out);
    }
    if (cd) {
        iconv_close(cd);
    }
    exit(status);
error:
    status = EXIT_FAILURE;
    goto exit;
}
```

Since UTF-16 is a variable-length encoding you're guessing how big your output buffer needs to be. A correct program should handle the case where the output buffer isn't large enough to hold the converted data.

You should also note that `iconv` doesn't `NULL`-terminate your output buffer for you.

Iconv is a stream-oriented processor, so you need to flush `iconv_t` if you want to reuse it for another conversion (the sample code does this near the end). If you want do stream processing you would handle the `EINVAL` error, copying any bytes left in the input buffer to the beginning of the new input buffer before calling `iconv` again.