# How to print UTF-16 LE in Linux?

Tags: c, linux

my XML file printed returns a error data when i used a FF FE to print a UTF-16 LE file.
i've also use the setlocale and wchar. Can someone explain me what is the cause of this?

```
#define XML_UNICODE   "\xFF\xFE"
#define XML_HEADER    "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\" standalone=\"yes\"?>"
```

Below is the snippet of my code:

```
int liIndex=0;
    int liSize=0;
    char* sTxt=NULL;
    wchar_t swTxt[LEN_XML_CONTENT];
    wchar_t swUnicode[MAX_BUFF];
    const char* cTxt;
const char* cUnicode;

    cUnicode=XML_UNICODE;
    mbstowcs(swUnicode, cUnicode, MAX_BUFF);
    fwprintf(file, L"%ls", swUnicode);

    cTxt=XML_HEADER;
    liSize=strlen(cTxt);
    mbstowcs(swTxt, cTxt, MAX_BUFF);
    for(liIndex=0; liIndex<liSize; liIndex++)
    {
        fwprintf(file, L"%lc", swTxt[liIndex]);
    }
    fwprintf(file, L"\n");
```

The output of XML file when check using notepad++, the encoding was UCS-2 LE already but the output was garbage/error.

Comment: See [How to Convert UTF-16 to UTF-32 and Print the Resulting wchar_t in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465939/how-to-convert-utf-16-to-utf-32-and-print-the-resulting-wchar-t-in-c).

Comment: Your first call to `mbstowcs` to convert the BOM looks incorrect. If your locale is UTF-8, the multi-byte representation of the BOM should be `"\xEF\xBB\xBF"`. If you are in a single-byte locale, you won't be able to represent the BOM in a multi-byte string anyway.

Comment: The requirements needed is to use \xFF\xFE. I've also tried using iconv -f <fromcode> -t <tocode> <oldfile> > <newfile> but the file doest print the required character like chinese and russian but the file was already in UTF16-LE.